# Python beautifulsoup how to get the line after 'href'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this piece of html:

```
<a href="http://francetv.fr/videos/alcaline_l_instant_,12163184.html"  class="ss-titre">
                                "Paris Combo"                   </a>    
<a href="http://francetv.fr/videos/jt20h_,12185324.html" class="ss-titre"> 
                            Journal         </a>
```

I can get `http://francetv.fr/videos/jt20h_,12185324.html` (example, not the real adress) but now,
I would like, using beautifulsoup, to get "Paris Combo", and "Journal".
I tried this:

```
for line in soup.findAll('/a'):
              title = line.get('</a>')
```

How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `find_all("a")` instead.

```
>>> for line in soup.find_all("a"):
...     print(line.text.strip())
"Paris Combo"
Journal
```

Comment: Yeah, that means you are using a previous version of BeautifulSoup. If you can you should consider upgrading to version 4

Comment: Ok, because I'm using Python 2.7 and Gtk2 ... Maybe I will learn python3... soon !

Comment: BeautifulSoup 4 works with Python 2.7 as well. It's faster and has a better memory footprint.

Comment: Ah ok! In Ubuntu, the package is "python-bs4" and not "python-beautifulsoup" (v3). Thanks for this precision