# Python associate urls's ids and url's titles in lists

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

continution of this question: [Python beautifulsoup how to get the line after 'href'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665526/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-get-the-line-after-href/23665984#23665984)

I have this HTML code

```
    <a href="http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/monte_le_son_live_,101973832.html" class="ss-titre"> 
                            Monte le son         </a>
    <div class="rs-cell-details">
                            <a href="http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/monte_le_son_live_,101973832.html"  class="ss-titre">
                                    "Rubin_Steiner"                 </a>
<a href="http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/fare_maohi_,102103928.html" class="ss-titre"> 
                        Fare maohi              </a>
```

As you see, "Monte le son" and ' "Rubin_Steiner" ' are associate with the same id (101973832) and "Fare maohi" is associate with the id 102103928.

So, actually I have these lists (example with one result, one id):

```
url = ['http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/monte_le_son_live_,101973832.html', 'http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/fare_maohi_,102103928.html']      
titles = ['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner', 'Fare maohi']   #2 entries for id 101973832
                                                           #1 entry for id 102103928
```

**Titles could have 3 entries, or 1, or none...**

How can I associate the Id of the adress (101973832) and the titles, to get this result:

```
result = ['"Monte le son Rubin_Steiner 101973832"', 'Fare maohi 102103928']
```

The result will be used to display in my Gtk interface. It need to contain the id to find the corresponding url like this:

```
choice = self.liste.get_active_text()     # choice = result   
for adress in url:
        if id in adress: 
            adresse = url
```

I hope my question is not too difficult to understand...

**Edit:**
I get the title and the urls like this:

```
url = "http://pluzz.francetv.fr/recherche?recherche=" + mot # mot is a word for my Gtk search
try:
   f = urllib.urlopen(url)
   page = f.read()
   f.close()
except: 
   self.champ.set_text("La recherche a échoué")
   pass    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
titres=[]
list_url=[]
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
     lien = link.get('href')
     if lien == None:
         lien = ""
     if "http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/" in lien:
         titre = (link.text.strip())
         if "Voir cette  vidéo" in titre:
              titre = ""
         if "Lire la vidéo" in titre:
              titre = ""
         titres.append(titre)
         list_url.append(lien)
```

Comment: @Guillame, do you want the "+" in between the elements?

Comment: No, just a space. It was just to explain

Comment: how are you getting the "page"?

Comment: give me an example of what "mot" is for the above examples.

Comment: any word, for example "maison" or "musique" (to find 'Monte le son')

Comment: using maison and your code returns empty lists

Comment: If I use "maison", the code returns 14 urls and 28 titles.
If I use "musique" 19 urls and 31 titles.

Comment: You can see at this link: http://pluzz.francetv.fr/recherche?recherche=musique
Ok I must leave now, I'll be back soon... Here is my code, if you want to see (I'm late, so it's bazaar in there...) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri3bs224eswy97m/dPluzz_v4.0.py.tar.gz

Comment: I will have a look later, try ` titres.append([titre])
         list_url.append([lien])` and see if they are grouped together.

Comment: I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684984/python-beautifulsoup-extracting-title-with-id

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and all your urls and titles will be in a list like your example.

```
import re

In [111]: titles = ['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner']

In [112]: url = ['http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/monte_le_son_live_,101973832.html']

In [113]: get_id = get_id = re.findall('\d+', url[0]) # find consecutive digits

In [114]: results = [x for x in titles] + get_id

In [115]: results
Out[115]: ['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner', '101973832']
```

As I say in my comments, when you add titles to your titles list, group corresponding titles in sublists, it is impossible to tell which belongs where without some way of indexing the groupings. I have grouped them in sublists to show you how it works.

```
In [3]: url = ['http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/monte_le_son_live_,101973832.html',   'http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/fare_maohi_,102103928.html']

In [4]: titles = [['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner'], ['Fare maohi']]   # need to sub list to match to url position

In [5]: get_ids = [re.findall('\d+', x) for x in url] # get all ids, position in list will match sub list position in titles

In [6]: results= [t + i for t, i in zip(titles, get_ids)] # this is why sub lists are useful, each position of the sub lists correspond.

In [7]: results

Out[7]: [['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner', '101973832'], ['Fare maohi', '102103928']]

In [11]: final_results=[ " ".join(y) for y in  results ]

In [12]: final_results

Out[12]: ['Monte le son Rubin_Steiner 101973832', 'Fare maohi 102103928'] # join strings in each sublist
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Hmm no, the result is not I would like. I would like to have the id at the end of each entry, like this: `result = ['abc id1', 'def id2', 'ghi id3']`

Comment: Or like this should be better: `result = ['title1 id1', 'title2 id2', 'title3 id3']`

Comment: show in your question using your examples url and titles exactly how you want it to look, also if each url and set of titles are different the example should work. Are there different urls in each list or how are they stored, it will be impossible to associate titles with ids if they are all in one list.

Comment: you need to add each title or group of titles in sublists to differentiate which belongs to which url.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I found this error: `results= [t + i for t, i in zip(self.titres, get_ids)] TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found` I think "for t, i" is not accepted (I'm using python 2.7, maybe it's the reason)

Comment: when you get you titles data, you need to sublist it like my example. `titles = [['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner'], ['Fare maohi']] ` you are adding it to one list, as I commented you need to put each title or group of titles in a sublist of its own to match up to the id/url it comes from.

Comment: Ah ok, I've understood. Can I convert "titles", or must I get it from the begining?

Comment: Whatever way you get the urls, you need at that point add a list of the titles corresponding to that whether it is 0,1,3 or 20 titles you need to add [title/titles] to a list.So all_titles=[[title/titles].[title/titles][] ....]

Comment: I don't know how to get: `titles = [['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner'], ['Fare maohi']]` so can you help me again? (sorry for that)

Comment: how are you getting the titles? Share your code and the link and I will see how to do it

Comment: I've edited my question to show you the code I'm using.. For this moment I've: `titles = ['Monte le son', 'Rubin_Steiner', 'Fare maohi']`